# How to call child's method from parent without using Refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I've a parent component `A` and a child `B`:

**A**:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {data: []};
  }

  handleClick = () => { 
  // api call
  // set data state to the returned value from api
  // call B's createTable method
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=> this.handleClick()}>Fetch data</button>
        <B data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
  }
}
```

**B**:

```
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {...};
  }

  createTable = () => {
    const { data } = this.props;
    // do smth
  }

  render() {
    return(...);
  }
}
```

I want to call `createTable` method from `A` without using `Refs`.

What I've done so far is using `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method in `B` to check if `data` prop has changed or not, If it changed call `createTable` method but I want to know is this right? or there's a better way of doing it because I feel it is kinda hacky or maybe bad design.

```
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {...};
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data !== prevProps.data) {
      this.createTable();
    }
  }

  createTable = () => {
    const { data } = this.props;
    // do smth
  }

  render() {
    return(...);
  }
}
```

**NOTE** I don't want to use hooks either just class based component.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` (what you're doing) would be a decent way to do this.

Comment: I think this the correct way, or another way basically you can call the callback function when your api gets resolved and that function will be passed as the prop to the B component and you can call that function directly you can name it as createTable itself so you will get the new data. if you use lifecycle it makes sure whenever the data is changed only it will trigger.

Comment: @apokryfos I think it's only me who sees it hacky :D, Did you see it being used like that before anywhere?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I see, actually passing the callback is brilliant! But if there's no api call say I get the value from a drop-down that will leave me `componentDidUpdate` way, correct?

Comment: @Mohamed yep, i think js is one of the best language and react is best library where you can write your code in such a way what you require no restrictions nothing :)

Comment: @Mohamed if the callback function solves the problem will add that one as the answer and it will be helpful for future reference

Comment: The "hacky" bit is comparing past and current props. If a change in `data` is the only reason the component ever gets updated then you can skip that and just have the result of `createTable` rendered every time the component is rendered

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I didn't try it yet tbh but the concept is brilliant, I'm leaning more to use `componentDidUpdate` as a generic solution but i'm trying to validate the idea first but your answer definitely will help others I'll up vote it myself.

Comment: @apokryfos The fetched data needs some modification first before displaying it that's why I need to call `createTable` first and not passing it directly as a prop.

Comment: You don't need to pass it directly as props but you can do something like `return (...{this.createTable()}..)` (assuming create table returns a table component

Comment: @apokryfos But that defeats the purpose of my question/intention I want to separate A's and B's methods from each other. I want A to have some common methods while B have all the table related goodies.

Comment: Why don't you make `B` a `PureComponent`, so it only re-renders, when `data` prop has changed, after `A` has finished fetchign?

Comment: @ford04 The fetched data needs some modification first before displaying it + read my last comment

Comment: The code I'm mentioning goes in `B`

Comment: @apokryfos `createTable` returns array of objects not a component which will be used to render the Table component

Comment: My point is, there's no need to compare states, you can just run this code on every component update and just make sure the component is only rendered when there's new data being passed (e.g. it can be a `PureComponent`)

Comment: @apokryfos I get you now pass the fetched data as a prop and pass it to the Table component like `<Table data={this.createTable(this.props.data)} />` this solution is way better I understand it was just I had another situation a similar function to `createTable` but async. I guess I need to refactor the code again thank you so much for taking the time to help me I'll update you once I do that.

Answer (score 0):

The following example might be useful

```
class Parent extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child setClick={click => this.clickChild = click}/>
      <button onClick={() => this.clickChild()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

class Child extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getAlert = this.getAlert.bind(this);
 }
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setClick(this.getAlert);
 }
 getAlert() {
    alert('clicked');
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <h1 ref="hello">Hello</h1>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, But can you provide some explanation? I can see that you're setting references but I can't understand this line `this.props.setClick(this.getAlert);`

Comment: What it does is to set the parent's clickChild method when child is mounted. In this way when you click the button in parent it will call clickChild which calls child's getAlert.

Note you can't use `onClick={this.clickChild}` in parent because when parent is rendered child is not mounted so `this.clickChild` is not assigned yet. Using `onClick={() => this.clickChild()}` is fine because when you click the button `this.clickChild` should already be assigned.

Comment: Its just my first time seeing `this.props.setClick(...);` isn't that impossible? Since data flow is one way from parent to child?